# INVALID_SESSION_ID using partner/enterprise wsdl for two different SF users

Tags: salesforce

I followed example given on [this link](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_for_ASP.NET_Developers), it worked perfectly for my SF developer account.

But when I tried the same with different SF credentials without changing web service reference (as other account also had apex web service methods to pull leads detail) it gave me below error (I passed correct username, password with access token for both users).

> INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal
>   Session. Session not found, missing session key:

My question is  : How .NET app authenticate and access respective Apex web service for multiple SF users?

Comment: Can you post your code? Are you calling the login webservice before trying to make other actions?

Answer (score 0):

make sure in  "session settings"  the "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated" is unchecked.