# INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session

Tags: php, session, soap, zend-framework2, salesforce

**Similar issues** -
[INVALID_SESSION_ID using partner/enterprise wsdl for two different SF users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028441/invalid-session-id-using-partner-enterprise-wsdl-for-two-different-sf-users) - Tried solution but didn't work.

I was trying to use Salesforce PHP toolkit with ZF 2. I have added namespace to php files in salesforce soap client and used it in zend controller.

Added follwing line to all php files in Salesforce SOAP client library.

[image]

```
namespace Salesforce\Soapclient;
```

Then included it in ZF controller.

```
use Salesforce\Soapclient;
```

Here is the connetion code -

```
    $empid = 'e1234567';
    $sf_WSDL = 'C:\wamp\www\myapp\app\vendor\salesforce\wsdl\enterprise.wsdl.xml';
    $sf_username = $config['salesforce']['username'];
    $sf_password = $config['salesforce']['password'];
    $sf_token = $config['salesforce']['token'];
    /***********/


    try {
        // Create SOAP client instance
        $sfSoapClient = new Soapclient\SforceEnterpriseClient();
        // Create connection
        $sfSoapClient->createConnection($sf_WSDL);

        var_dump($_SESSION['enterpriseSessionId']);

        if (isset($_SESSION['enterpriseSessionId'])) {

            $location = $_SESSION['enterpriseLocation'];
            $sessionId = $_SESSION['enterpriseSessionId'];

            $sfSoapClient->setEndpoint($location);
            $sfSoapClient->setSessionHeader($sessionId);

        } else {
            // Login to SF
            $sfSoapClient->login($sf_username,$sf_password . $sf_token);
            $_SESSION['enterpriseLocation'] = $sfSoapClient->getLocation();
            $_SESSION['enterpriseSessionId'] = $sfSoapClient->getSessionId();
        }
        var_dump($_SESSION['enterpriseSessionId']);
        // Get candidate profile by employee id
        $candidate_profile = $this->getCandidateTable()->getCandidateByEmpId($empid);
        $ids = array();
        array_push($ids, $empid);

        // If no profile for logged internal employee
        if (!$candidate_profile){
            $query = "SELECT Id, First_Name__c from Employee__c";
            $response = $sfSoapClient->query($query);

            echo "Results of query '$query'<br/><br/>\n";
            foreach ($response->records as $record) {
                echo $record->Id . ": " . $record->First_Name__c . "<br/>\n";
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        //TODO Handle error login exception
        die('Connection could not established.');
    }
```

But I'm getting following error -

> INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal
>   Session

Note that "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated" setting is turned off.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @hakre How to solve "INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session" issue ?

Comment: @ChamingaD http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Perl-PHP-Python-Ruby-Development/INVALID-SESSION-ID-Invalid-Session-ID-found-in-SessionHeader/td-p/66846

Comment: @DarylGill already tried that. but didn't work.